# How to responsively change the height of Bootstrap Carousel between two CSS media query breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a `carousel` created using `Bootstrap`. But when I resize the window (decrease size), everything works responsive (header text, description and button of `carousel`) but its height is not changing (where I need to decrease height when I'm reducing the browser window).

I need to reduce the `carousel` height GRADUALLY and PERFECTLY (maybe giving height as a percentage?) when I'm reducing the browser window. Not like suddenly reducing throughout the given breaking points (577px to 1024px), but reducing height smoothly.

This is the `html` code for `carousel`

```
<!--Carousel-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="first-slide" src="images/A.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
                    <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                    <p id="carousel-text">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a id="carousel-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="second-slide" src="images/B.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a id="carousel-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="images/C.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-right">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a id="carousel-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="images/D.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a id="carousel-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="images/E.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a id="carousel-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="images/F.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-right">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a id="carousel-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="images/G.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a id="carousel-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
<!--End of carousel-->
```

This is the `css` I'm using for media queries:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 577px) {
    .carousel-inner, #myCarousel {
        height: 50% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having trouble recreating the issue from your code could you give a working example and link it here?

Comment: This is the only code I used Sir... The `HTML` part and the only `css` part which handles the media query...

Comment: with your code: https://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/rGwprN

Comment: Can you provide me with the right directions how to decrease the height of a `div` gradually and firmly when resizing the window???

Comment: It's not possible to recreating the issue, you should provide a working code... this is your code on jsfiddle, adding bootstrap4 css and js as external libraries https://jsfiddle.net/u40vqvmz/

Comment: did you follow this example? - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/